# Consulta por Encuesta

Tags: google-forms

soy nuevo en el foro y quería consultar si es posible compartir una encuesta orientada a Desarrolladores de Software que estamos realizando con mis compañeros de la Universidad. El objetivo es poder obtener información para la materia Seminario de Integración Profesional de UADE.

Hago la consulta para saber si se pueden publicar este tipo de encuestas en el foro.

Muchas gracias.
Sebastian.

Comment: Este sitio **no es un foro**, es para preguntas y respuestas relacionadas con la programación, pero no encuestas, lo siento. Si te lees [ask] y [tour] aprenderás el funcionamiento del sitio, y tu mismo verás que tu encuesta no será bien recibida en este sitio.

Comment: Muchas gracias por aclararme el funcionamiento del sitio, por eso preferí consultar primero. Nuevamente gracias.

Comment: De nada, siempre serás bienvenido mientras tus preguntas sigan las pautas marcadas en los enlaces anteriores. Lo siento nuevamente y agradezco tu comprensión.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por la info, leeré bien los dos enlaces. Saludos.